# "Layer is not valid" when importing WFS

Tags: qgis, layers, wfs

I try to load a WFS layer but

> *Analysis of DescribeFeatureType response failed for url  restrictToRequestBBOX='1' srsname='EPSG:3877' typename='akaava:Kaava'
>   url='https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.ashx' version='auto'
>   table="" sql=: it is probably a schema for Complex Features*

The URL contains open source information of a city I'm making a map of. The WMS services work just fine but the WFS doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Believe the message. The schemata of the featuretypes are not of "Simple Feature" type which is what QGIS supports. Instead they are complex. One schema location is at http://www.paikkatietopalvelu.fi/gml/kantakartta/2.1.1/kantakartta.xsd. QGIS does not know how to handle such schema. WFS works, and I would say that QGIS works as well, it is just missing support for Complex Features.

Answer (score 2):

You can't read complex features from that WFS server with QGIS, at least not yet. However, you can use the new GDAL GMLAS driver http://gdal.org/drv_gmlas.html that is currently in GDAL trunk only.

Usage examples:

Get layer list:

```
ogrinfo -ro WFS:"https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.
ashx?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities"
INFO: Open of `WFS:https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.ashx?service=WFS&
request=GetCapabilities'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  TITLE=Tekla Xcity WFS Server
1: kanta:Kiinteisto (Polygon)
2: kanta:Kiinteistoraja (Line String)
3: kanta:Maaraala (Polygon)
4: kanta:Rajamerkki (Point)
5: kanta:Rakennuspaikka (Polygon)
6: kanta:Kayttooikeusyksikko (Point)
7: kanta:MuuMaa-alue (Point)
...
...
```

Study structure of one layer:

```
ogrinfo -ro -so WFS:"https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.ashx?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities" akaava:Kaavayksikko
INFO: Open of `WFS:https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.ashx?service=WFS&
request=GetCapabilities'
      using driver `WFS' successful.
Metadata:
  TITLE=Tekla Xcity WFS Server

Layer name: akaava:Kaavayksikko
Metadata:
  TITLE=akaava:Kaavayksikko
Geometry: Polygon
...lots of warnings...
Feature Count: 100
Extent: (23456398.990000, 6697268.529000) - (23474000.214000, 6714794.315000)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / GK23FIN",
    GEOGCS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",23],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",23500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3877"]]
gml_id: String (0.0) NOT NULL
tunnus: Integer (0.0)
kohdekoodi: Integer (0.0)
kaavayksikonTunnus: Integer (0.0)
kaavayksikonlaji: String (0.0)
tonttijaonlaji: String (0.0)
tonttijaontunnus: String (0.0)
kaavallinenOlotila: Integer (0.0)
voimassaolo: String (0.0)
perusmaara: Real (0.0)
kaytetty: Real (0.0)
lisarakennusoikeus: Integer (0.0)
kellaritilat: Integer (0.0)
ullakkotilat: Integer (0.0)
kerrostenLkm: Integer (0.0)
maanalaistenTilojenLkm: Integer (0.0)
kerrosjaonMaaraytymistapa: Integer (0.0)
tehokkuusluku: Real (0.0)
maarittamisTapaKoodi: String (0.0)
pintaAla: Real (0.0)
pintaAlanMaarittamistapa: String (0.0)
kayttotarkoitus: String (0.0)
yksilointitieto: Integer (0.0)
alkuHetki: String (0.0)
kunta: String (0.0)
teksti: String (0.0)
osoitenumero: Integer (0.0)
postinumero: Integer (0.0)
postitoimipaikannimi: String (0.0)
```

Leave out the -so (summary only switch) and you can print data about the features on screen. You can even try to convert data into SpatiaLite database:

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes virkistysalue.sqlite WFS:"https://opaskartta.turku.fi/TeklaOGCWeb/WFS.ashx?service=WFS&request=Get
Capabilities" akaava:Virkistysalue -skipfailures
```

However, the result will have no features. I am not sure if my syntax is wrong or if the error message is right and layers in that service are not configured correctly:

```
 NOT NULL constraint failed: akaava:virkistysalue.gml_id (19)
```

As the next steps I would read carefully GDAL GMLAS document page, have a try with saving data from the service into GML with curl and simple GetFeature request, and try if data could be converted better from disk as

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite -dsco spatialite=yes GMLAS:virkistysalue.gml
```

If there are still error messages about schema validation errors contact those who maintain the service.